# How to transform ellipse to circle using opencv?

Tags: python, opencv

I have a picture of a coin taken with a phone camera. Because of the angle of the picture, the coin is shown elliptical. I want to transform the image of the coin such that the coin is shown circular. How could I do that?

This is original picture:
[image]

This is my result:
[image]

And this is what I expect:
[image]

Comment: You should include the original image so that we can start working straight away and also show what you have tried up till now.

Comment: Also, what kind of programming language are you planning to use?

Comment: looks like you already have found the shapes but some problem with the height. If you search for "opencv measure object size" you would find some solution

Comment: @VardanAgarwal I have already update pictures.

Comment: @M.Martin I'm planning to use Python first